# How to detect the user has logged in a domain or local host in the linux shell script?

Tags: linux, shell-script, domain

In the default, the linux doesn't support the domain. But the user can join a domain by applictions, such as: Likewise, Winbind, and so on.
For my project, my customers are all enterprise members. For the security problem, most customers' linux host will be joined a domain.
Unfortunately, the customer can log in the local host even the linux host has been joined a domain. Such as:
(1) The are two accounts in a linux host:
    a domain account: dev.com\john(the domain is developer.com)
    a local account: tom
(2) The customer can log in with the domain account(dev.com\john) or local account(tom) freely.

My task is that write a shell script that will be executed when the user log in. In the shell script, I need to check the user log in with a domain account or a local account.
If the user log in with the domain name, I need to get the domain name ; otherwise, I need to get the host name. Then report the domain(or host) name and user name to the remote monitor server.

I have tried the following code:

```
hostName=$(hostname)  
hostFQDN=$(hostname -f)  

if [ "$hostName" = "$hostFQDN" ]; then  
    # The user didn't log in a domain.  
    hostInfo="$hostName"  
else  
    # The user logged in a domain.  
    hostInfo=$(hostname -d)  
fi
```

In the above, I check the host FQDN is equal with the host name or not. If yes, I will believe the customer log in with the domain account; else, local account.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work always. The reason is that the host FQDN will  not equal with host name always if the linux host is joined a domain, even the customer log in with a local account. Such as:
(1) The linux host is joined the domain "dev.com";
(2) The host fqdn will be "yw-host.dev.com" always("yw-host" is the host name), whether the customer log in with domain account or not.

Anybody can give a solution please?  As my customer can join the domain with multiple domain applications(such as: likewise, winbin, and so on), it is better the solution will not depend on a special domain application.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have an idea that check the user id is in the file etc/passwd or not. If yes, it should be a local account; else, a domain account. I am not sure this solution is correct or not.

Comment: Anybody can give some comments? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The full user login detail should be in your secure or audit log depending on which distro you are using. 
It is a simple quick fix to check if they exist in /etc/passwd but you could have issues with duplicate usernames.